# jvm option -Xloggc with %p in systemd.unit gives wrong log filename

Tags: java, systemd

I have a java process that I want to run with the option:

```
-Xloggc:/var/log/mylog_%p.gc.log
```

so that the name of the log file contains the PID. For example, if the process has PID 3498, the logfile name is `/var/log/mylog_pid3498.gc.log`.
I want the Java process to be initiated by a **systemd unit** file.
The unit file is:

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/my_code
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Xloggc:/var/log/mylog_%%p.gc.log -jar my_code.jar
Restart=always
```

Note that I have used the `%%` character to escape the `%`. However, this does not give the expected result, since I get that the log file has name `/var/log/mylog_%p.gc.log` , i.e. Java could not do the substitution of `%p` with the actual PID.

Any idea? Thanks!

Operating system:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1066-aws x86_64)
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

systemd version:

```
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

Comment: This question, as it stands, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get better help on https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll post my question there. Sorry for picking the wrong channel.